# Como poder llamar una función en PHP

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Programo en `PHP`, pero tengo una duda y no encuentro como solventarla.

Estoy listando unas líneas que leo de una tabla, el problema es que al terminar cada línea tengo que hacer la grabación de esos datos en otra tabla y me da un error `call to undefined function guardarLinea()` y no puedo hacer la grabación.

```
   "<td>" . $entidad  . "</td>" .
   "<td>" . $oficina  . "</td>" .
   "<td>" . $dc  . "</td>" .
   "<td>" . $cuentaban  . "</td>" .
   "</tr>";   
   $tbruto = number_format(round($unaLinea[0]['PVP'], 6), 2, '.', ',');
   guardarlinea(); 
} else {
   $valororden = $valororden + 1;
```

No se como poder llamar a función `guardarlinea()` y hacer la grabación de esa línea.

La parte completa es la siguiente ....
                                        '   if ($unaLinea[0]['PRORRATEADO'] == 0) {
                                                $valororden = $valororden + 1;
                                                $unaLinea['PVP'] = round(($unaLinea['PVP'] / 1.21), 6);
                                        //  $valorcomis = (($unaLinea['PVP'] * $unaLinea['DTO']) / 100);

```
                                            $preciofinal = $unaLinea['PVP'];
                                            $imporiva = round(((($preciofinal) * 21) / 100), 6) ;
                                            $valor = $preciofinal + $imporiva ;

                                      echo  "<tr>" .
                                            "<td>" . $valororden . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $unaLinea['NUMERO'] . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $fecha . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $unaLinea['ID_PROYECTO'] . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $cliente . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $nombrecliente . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $direccion . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $poblacion . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $codpost . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $provincia . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $unaLinea['CIF'] . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $unaLinea['NUMERO'] . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . number_format(round($unaLinea['PVP'], 6), 2, '.', ',') . "</td>" . 
                                            "<td>" . $unaLinea['DTO'] . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $descuento . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . number_format(round($valorcomis, 2), 2, '.', ',') . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . number_format(round($preciofinal, 6), 2, '.', ',') . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . number_format(round($imporiva, 6), 2, '.', ',') . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . number_format(round($valor, 6), 2, '.', ','). "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $formaPago . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $iban . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $swift . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . " " . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $entidad  . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $oficina  . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $dc  . "</td>" .
                                            "<td>" . $cuentaban  . "</td>" .
                                            "</tr>";   
                                        $tbruto = number_format(round($unaLinea[0]['PVP'], 6), 2, '.', ',');
                                        $numero = $unaLinea['NUMERO'];
                                         $linea = "<tr><td>$valororden</td>
                                                       <td>$numero</td>
                                                       <td>$fecha</td>
                                                       <td>$unaLinea[ID_PROYECTO]</td>
                                                       <td>$cliente</td>
                                                       <td>$nombrecliente</td>
                                                       <td>$direccion</td>
                                                       <td>$poblacion</td>
                                                       <td>$codpost</td>
                                                       <td>$provincia</td>
                                                       <td>$unaLinea[CIF]</td>
                                                        <td>$numero</td>
                                                        <td>$preciofinal</td>
                                                        <td>$imporiva</td>
                                                        <td>$valor</td>
                                                        <td>$formaPago</td>
                                                        <td>$iban</td>
                                                        <td>$swift</td>
                                                        <td>$entidad</td>
                                                        <td>$oficina</td>
                                                        <td>$dc</td>
                                                        <td>$cuentaban</td></tr>";
                                         guardarlinea($linea); '
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así para simplificar:

### En el contexto

Crear una variable  `$linea` donde vas a escribir todo el contenido de la línea. Para más claridad he evitado tantas concatenaciones, porque no son necesarias, puedes escribir todo dentro de un contenido rodeado de comillas dobles, incluyendo las variables.

Luego llamas a `guardarLinea()` pasándola la variable.

```
$linea="<tr>
            <td>$entidad</td>
            <td>$oficina</td>
            <td>$dc</td>
            <td>$cuentaban</td>
        </tr>"; 
guardarLinea($linea);
```

### La función

Quedaría definida así, recibiendo un parámetro `$linea` para guardarlo donde haga falta.

```
function guardarLinea($linea) {
    #Guardar la variable $linea donde tengas que guardarla  
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101452/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-como-poder-llamar-una-funcion-en-php).

Answer (score 1):

Primero tienes que crear la función `guardarlinea();`

```
Function guardarlinea(aquí pones lo parametros){
    // aquí dentro pones lo que vas a querer mostrar

    // y luego hacer un return para devolver el valor de tus variables
};
```

Después aquí fuera llamas la función `guardarlinea();`.

Comment: Ojo, la palabra function no tiene por qué iniciaren mayúscula

Comment: la fucion ya la tenia creada, lo que no hacia era enviarle los parametros....voya intentar lo que me comenta A.Cedano de crear un  campo donde alojar la nformacion a grabar..... Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda.